# their truth as aspects of a cycle of existence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Hell everyone,
I don't understand the part in italic. I'd appreciate it if you'd clarify it.

The self-imposed restrictions of Dickinson’s actual life were more than matched by her ability to see the universal in the particular and vice versa. She perceived the relationship between a drop of dew and a flood, between a grain of sand and a desert. These perceptions helped her make metaphors that embraced experiences far beyond the limited compass of Amherst village life.
Still, no matter how far her imagination ranged, Dickinson never denied those experiences *their truth as aspects of a cycle of existence* important in itself. When an Amherst neighbor’s barn caught fire and lit up the sky, it was a real barn at the edge of a real pasture, and its loss became a matter of local anguish.

[Source](http://mryoungmansenglishclass.weebly.com/emily-dickinson.html)

Comment: It's almost meaningless. The person who wrote this obviously wasn't as good a writer  as Dickinson herself.  Please say what it is that you don't understand. Do you have a question about the grammar? The dictionary meaning of any of the words? What precisely are you asking?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I think there should be a comma after "experiences". I'm wondering if what follows "experiences" defines the meaning of "experiences" in other words? Or it's not to do with experiences?

Comment: @ Purfecr - Okay I understand now. You have parsed the sentence incorrectly. I'll write an answer.

Comment: This Q is very localized. I don't see how it benefits the site to interpret it in a proper answer. A comment should be enough to explain how to parse the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> Dickinson never denied those experiences their truth as aspects of a
> cycle of existence important in itself.

The experiences have been personified. If you deny someone something, it means that you refuse to let them have that thing. You withhold that thing. Normally this refers only to living beings, e.g.

*The interrogators denied their captive sleep in an attempt to get him to confess.*

*The owner was reported to the authorities because he deliberately denied his dog  food. The poor animal was emaciated.*

The author states that the experiences "have" their own truth. This truth belongs to the experiences. Dickinson allowed the experiences to have their truth - she did not withhold it from them.

Like I said it's poor writing but disguised with flowery language.  It is pretty much nonsense.

Does  that help?

Comment: It sure does. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "'Like I said' it's  'poor writing'"...Oh My Dog I cannot believe you put both those phrases together.

Comment: @Cascabel - Haha! :-)